# iOS-PhoneGap: Listview not refreshing after dynamically loading of data

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I'm trying to generate a listview from the database. I'm retrieving from MySQL database, after refreshing the listview, the CSS or design is not updated.

The listview is generate upon clicking of a list item from another page in phonegap

Javascript:

```
$('#facilityListView li').live('click',function(){
    var selectedFacility = $(this).attr('name');
    var appendFacilityType = $('#facilitySpecificType');
    var fContent = "";

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data: {sFacility:selectedFacility},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: '5000',
        url: 'http://localhost/getSpecificFacilityCategory.php',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(f,fitem){
                fContent += '<li><a href="#">' + fitem.FacilityName+ '</a></li>';
            });
            appendFacilityType.empty().append(fContent).listview("refresh");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failed");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
```

**Fixed Version**

```
$('#facilityListView li').on('click', 'li' ,function(){
    var selectedFacility = $(this).attr('name');
    var appendFacilityType = $('#facilitySpecificType');
    var fContent = "";

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data: {sFacility:selectedFacility},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: '5000',
        url: 'http://localhost/getSpecificFacilityCategory.php',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(f,fitem){
                fContent += '<li><a href="#">' + fitem.FacilityName+ '</a></li>';
            });
            appendFacilityType.empty().append(fContent).listview("refresh");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failed");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: There are many unanswered questions looking at what you have above. First off, how are you running PHP on your iOS device? If you're using another library for this, you may want to list it as well. Have you verified that your PHP page is actually returning the elements that you want? When you do this, is the ajax success or error function getting hit?

Comment: @JamieStarke I'm actually programming using a common platform, which is phonegap, so i connect to the PHP using $.ajax function

Comment: Yes, I'm quite familiar with Phonegap, but in your example, you're making that call to `http://localhost/getSpecificFacilityCategory.php` which when you're on the phone will attempt to contact the phone itself.

Comment: @JamieStarke Hi, I'm sorry my wrong...its actually connected to my online hosting web server

Comment: Ok, care to update your code with the correct address, because if this the JavaScript, then the `localhost` will literally mean the device that you're running on, meaning your iOS device.

Comment: @JamieStarke thank you so much, i found out why it doesn't work $.live is deprecated. After I changed to $.on it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing the same problem, this issue was caused by the fact that the `.live` function was [deprecated in JQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc) in favor of the `.on` function.

The correct solution looks like:

```
$('#facilityListView li').on('click', 'li' ,function(){
    var selectedFacility = $(this).attr('name');
    var appendFacilityType = $('#facilitySpecificType');
    var fContent = "";

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data: {sFacility:selectedFacility},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: '5000',
        url: 'http://localhost/getSpecificFacilityCategory.php',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data,function(f,fitem){
                fContent += '<li><a href="#">' + fitem.FacilityName+ '</a></li>';
            });
            appendFacilityType.empty().append(fContent).listview("refresh");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failed");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
```